# On Android, I cannot get actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE to work outside the App Actions Test Tool

Tags: android, android-intent, app-actions

I'm trying to get the Android Assistant to open my application and pass it a string parameter. Currently I can use the App Actions Test Tool to do that. However, if I open the assistant and type in, or say, `open <App Name> <parameter string>`, I just get web results back. Here is what my actions.xml looks like:

```
<actions xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <action intentName="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
        <fulfillment urlTemplate="https://run-main-activity.com{?featureName}">
            <parameter-mapping
                intentParameter="feature"
                urlParameter="featureName" />
        </fulfillment>
    </action>
</actions>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: The application works, it's the integration with the assistant that doesn't. That's why I posted the action. Is there something in specific you need to see?

Answer (score 0):

It should be fixed now. Please try it again and keep us posted. You can find more here. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135714718